# Filter list of dict based on values from another dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries `list_of_dict`, a set of keys `set_of_keys` and another dictionary `dict_to_compare`.

I need to filter the list of dicts if the values of any two of the three possible keys matches the values from `dict_to_compare`.

**Input:**

```
set_of_keys = {'val1', 'val2', 'val3'}

dict_to_compare = {'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2','k3':'val6'}

list_of_dict = [
        {'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2', 'k3':'val3'},
        {'k1': 'val4', 'k2': 'val5', 'k3':'val6'},
        {'k1': 'val7', 'k2': 'val8', 'k3':'val9'}
]
```

**Output:**

```
 out = [{'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2', 'k3': 'val3'}] #First element from list
```

- All elements in `list_of_dicts` have same keys.
- `dict_to_compare` also have same keys as elements of `list_of_dicts`.
- Multiple elements from `list_of_dicts` can be matched.
- Values against any combination of two keys should be matched not all three.

I tried doing this by explicitly specifying bunch of `if` `elif` conditions. But the problem is set of keys is really huge. Is there a better way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: `out = [d for d in list_of_dict if sum([dict_to_compare[k] == d[k] for k in dict_to_compare]) > 1]`

Comment: Sorry I missed the last point about two matches but not three (seems like I was not the only one). Just change the `>1` in my comment above to `==2` and that should work. Or you can similarly modify one of the answers below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sum`:

```
dict_to_compare = {'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2','k3':'val6'}
set_of_keys = {'val1', 'val2', 'val3'}
list_of_dict = [
    {'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2', 'k3':'val3'},
    {'k1': 'val4', 'k2': 'val5', 'k3':'val6'},
    {'k1': 'val7', 'k2': 'val8', 'k3':'val9'}
]
final_list = [i for i in list_of_dict if sum(c in set_of_keys for c in i.values()) >= 2]
```

Output:

```
[{'k3': 'val3', 'k2': 'val2', 'k1': 'val1'}]
```

Comment: since you are doing membership tests to check the condition and casting to `list`, why not cast to `set` instead that would be faster?

Comment: It looks cleaner now. +1

Answer (score 5):

You can recreate the `list_of_dict` using a list-comprehension that features your desired filtering scheme:

```
set_of_keys = {'val1', 'val2', 'val3'}

dict_to_compare = {'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2','k3':'val6'}

list_of_dict = [
        {'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2', 'k3':'val3'},
        {'k1': 'val4', 'k2': 'val5', 'k3':'val6'},
        {'k1': 'val7', 'k2': 'val8', 'k3':'val9'}
]

list_of_dict = [d for d in list_of_dict if sum(1 for k, v in d.items() if dict_to_compare.get(k, None)==v)>1]
print(list_of_dict)  # -> [{'k1': 'val1', 'k2': 'val2', 'k3': 'val3'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood what you need, but this is my shot:

```
result = [i for i in list_of_dict if len([j for j in i.values() if j in dict_to_compare.values()]) == len(set_of_keys) - 1]
```

Comment: OP said at least 2, not maximum of 1 failing. I would go with `>1`

Answer (score 1):

My answer is similar to most of the answers here.

I would suggest you to use custom function that stops comparing keys when desired match count is achieved. Since you mentioned you have a lot of keys to compare, this would be beneficial.

```
def my_sum(gen,count_needed):
    for e in gen:                 #gen is a generator
        if e:                     #e is true when keys match
            count_needed -= 1
            if count_needed==0:   #stop comparison when desired no.of matches is found
                return True
    return False


count_needed = 2
out = [ d for d in list_of_dict
        if my_sum( (d[key] == dict_to_compare[key] for key in d) ,count_needed) 
]
```